# Excel VBA - Compare values in two columns and copy matched row to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare column A in sheet2 to columnA in sheet1 and when there's a match, copy the row from sheet1 to sheet3.  Here's the code I have but it's not working.

```
Sub compareAndCopy()

Dim lastRowE As Integer
Dim lastRowM As Integer
Dim foundTrue As Boolean

' stop screen from updating to speed things up
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRowE = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowF = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowM = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Sheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row



For i = 1 To lastRowE
foundTrue = False
For j = 1 To lastRowF

    If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
        'MsgBox ("didnt find string: " & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).value)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
        Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(lastRowM + 1)

        Exit For
    End If

Next j

If Not foundTrue Then
    lastRowM = lastRowM + 1
    foundTrue = True

End If


Next i

' stop screen from updating to speed things up
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please be more specific as to the problem.  What is not working? does it throw an error? if so, on which line?

Comment: Your narrative and your code do not match.  In your narrative you say you want to transfer sheet 1 to sheet 3 but you are transferring sheet 2 to sheet 3.  Which is it?  Also what is with the foundTrue, you are not really using it, why have the extra code?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Scott Craner, your updating of `lastRowM` based on `foundTrue` is not working.  `foundTrue` isn't really needed, as long as you update `lastRowM` each time you add a new row to Sheet3.  I have kept it in the code in case you **do** want to display a message if the value isn't found.

```
Sub compareAndCopy()

    Dim lastRowE As Long
    Dim lastRowF As Long
    Dim lastRowM As Long
    Dim foundTrue As Boolean

    ' stop screen from updating to speed things up
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastRowE = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowF = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowM = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Sheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRowE
        foundTrue = False
        For j = 1 To lastRowF

            If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                lastRowM = lastRowM + 1
                Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
                           Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(lastRowM)
                foundTrue = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        'If Not foundTrue Then
        '    MsgBox ("didn't find string: " & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).value)
        'End If
    Next i

    ' stop screen from updating to speed things up
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

following your wording:

> I'm trying to compare column A in sheet2 to columnA in sheet1 and when
>   there's a match, copy the row from sheet1 to sheet3.

you may try this

```
Sub RowFinder()
    Dim sheet1Data As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sht2") '<--| reference your worksheet 2
        sheet1Data = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value)
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sht1") '<--| reference your worksheet 1
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A cells from row 1 (header) down to last not empty one
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=sheet1Data, Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter cells with sheet 2 column A values
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sht3").Range("A1")
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```